# How Can I Hide Filters in Layered Navigation?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have a magento store that i'm building out, and the only filter I need to show in the layered nav is Categories. How can I hide the other filters?

Answer (score 1):

Go to attributes in the backend, and select an attribute you want to remove from filters. Set the "used in layered navigation" to false for the category.